# Angular(typescript) 401 unauthorized error issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-oauth, access-token

I've used the similar approach using Angular(Type script) and facing "GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo 401 (Unauthorized)" error on console I don't know what is wrong here the access token is correct and the token hasn't expired yet!

private userInfoUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo';

getUserInfo(accessToken: string): Observable {
const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${accessToken}`);
return this.http.get(this.userInfoUrl, { headers });
}

Comment: Have you tried 'withCredentials: true'